# Scheduling reset every 24 hours at midnight

Tags: akka, scala-2.10, playframework-2.2

I have a counter "numberOrders" and i want to reset it everyday at midnight, to know how many orders I get in one day, what I have right now is this:

```
val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
system.scheduler.schedule(86400000 milliseconds, 0 milliseconds){(numberOrders = 0)}
```

This piece of code is inside a def which is called every time i get a new order, so want it does is: reset numberOrders after 24hours from the first order or from every order, I'm not really sure if every time there's a new order is going to reset after 24 hours, which is not what I want. I want to rest the variable everyday at midnight, any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI: the duration DSL supports `hours`, so feel free to use `24 hours` instead of `86400000 milliseconds` ;)

Comment: I tried but it was complaining about the hours

Comment: type mismatch; found : Int(24) required: ?{def hours: ?} Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous: both method RichInt in trait IntImplicits of type (n: Int)com.github.nscala_time.time.RichInt and method DurationInt in package duration of type (n: Int)concurrent.duration.DurationInt are possible conversion functions from Int(24) to ?{def hours: ?}

Answer (score 2):

To further increase pushy's answer. Since you might not always be sure when the site started and if you want to be exactly sure it runs at midnight you can do the following

```
val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
val wait = (24 hours).toMillis - System.currentTimeMillis
system.scheduler.schedule(Duration.apply(wait, MILLISECONDS), 24 hours, orderActor, ResetCounterMessage)
```

Might not be the tidiest of solutions but it does the job.

Comment: Note that this solution is not DST safe. hello from 2019.

Answer (score 1):

As schedule supports repeated executions, you could just set the interval parameter to 24 hours, the initial delay to the amount of time between now and midnight, and initiate the code at startup. You seem to be creating a new actorSystem every time you get an order right now, that does not seem quite right, and you would be rid of that as well.

Also I would suggest using the schedule method which sends messages to actors instead. This way the actor that processes the order could keep count, and if it receives a ResetCounter message it would simply reset the counter. You could simply write:

```
 system.scheduler.schedule(x seconds, 24 hours, orderActor, ResetCounterMessage)
```

when you start up your actor system initially, and be done with it.